# how to run nodejs script from ruby on rails in production mode

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, node.js, production-environment

In my project am trying to run nodejs script from ruby on rails.

Am running in my product_details_controller like this:

```
system "node /home/user1/sample.js"
```

In sample.js am doing like this:

```
var jsdom = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jsdom'),
    request = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/request');
var _mysql = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mysql');
var MYSQL_USER = 'root';
var MYSQL_PASS = 'abc';
var DATABASE = 'example';
var mysql = _mysql.createClient({
    user: MYSQL_USER,
    password: MYSQL_PASS,
});
mysql.query('USE ' + DATABASE);
mysql.query('select * from product_details',
    function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
            for (var i in results) {
                var product = results[i];
                console.log(product);
            }
        }
    });
```

In development mode it is working fine. But when am trying deploy it in server am facing problem.

mysql.query('use '+DATABASE) is not executing and it is looping there only. I don't know how fix this. Please help. In errorlog am not getting errors also. Am not getting any errors and any response also. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling Node.js script from Rails app using ExecJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852086/calling-node-js-script-from-rails-app-using-execjs)